# Removing a property in ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, expandoobject

I am using an API to get a collection of JSON responses and I am putting them in an ExpandoObject `result`. The property I want to delete is in `result.data.attributes.image_url` for example. I don't need it and wish to remove it from the entire collection. So far I've tried:

```
result.data.attributes.Remove("image_url");
```

However I am getting the message that ExpandoObject does not have a "Remove" method. How exactly can I do this? In python I would just use the `del` keyword to delete a dataframe's column. What is a C# equivalent to this?

Comment: No, how do I delete a nested attribute? I've tried `dict.Remove("data.attributes.image");` but it didn't do anything. I'm not sure how to access it because its two levels down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First cast to a dictionary, then you should be able to call `Remove()`.

```
var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>) result.data.attributes;
dict.Remove("image_url");
```

Or an all-in-one-line version, IMO harder to read though:

```
((IDictionary<string, object>) result.data.attributes).Remove("image_url");
```